# Форматированный вывод TimeSpan

Tags: c#

Нужно получить текущее время, и сравнить - помещается ли оно в определенный промежуток времени(например: если сейчас 8:22, и оно помещается в промежуток между 8:00 и 9:00) отнять конец этого промежутка от настоящего времени и вывести его на экран. Все получается, но проблема в том, что после часов, минут, идут (как я понял) миллисекунды, и их много и они мешают. Возможно ли их убрать(как)?

Вот код:

```
var timeFrom1 = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0);
var timeTo1 = new TimeSpan(19, 30, 0);

var timeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
if (timeNow > timeFrom1 && timeNow < timeTo1)
{
    var timeResult1 = timeTo1 - timeNow;
    Console.WriteLine("осталось " + timeResult1);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка");
}
```

Comment: @Андрей Спасибо, разобрался!

Comment: @АндрейNOP: А почему не ответ?

Comment: @VladD, ответ! Осталось дождаться автора :)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [перегрузкой `TimeSpan.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx), принимающей параметром [выходной формат](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings), например, так:

```
Console.WriteLine("осталось " + timeResult1.ToString(@"mm\:ss"));
```

Тоже самое в виде интерполированной строки:

```
Console.WriteLine($@"осталось {timeResult1:mm\:ss}");
```

Будут выведены минуты и секунды разделенные двоеточием.